# Can't emulate browser behavior with requests

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, python-requests

I'm trying to send a post request to a website to get a json response. I can see the json response in Chrome Inspector when I click on a link, but I can get it using requests. 
Firstly I tried to used requests Session to get the cookies first and use them in the post request, to no avail.

```
session = requests.Session()
session.get('http://www.auchandrive.fr/drive/pagestatique.pagetemplate.popuphandler.popinchangementmagasin.changermag/537?t:ac=PAGE_STATIQUE_ENGAGEMENTS')
response = session.post('http://www.auchandrive.fr/drive/rayon.productlist.pagination_0.topage/1?t:ac=3686973/3686997')
print response.text
```

Secondly I used Selenium+PhantomJS to get the cookies and used them in requests, no results!

```
browser = webdriver.PhantomJS(PHANTOMJS_PATH)
browser.get('http://www.auchandrive.fr/drive/pagestatique.pagetemplate.popuphandler.popinchangementmagasin.changermag/537?t:ac=PAGE_STATIQUE_ENGAGEMENTS')
all_cookie = {}
for cookie in browser.get_cookies():
    all_cookie[cookie['name']] = cookie['value']
rep = requests.post('http://www.auchandrive.fr/drive/rayon.productlist.pagination_0.topage/1?t:ac=3686973/3686997', cookies=all_cookie)
```

It only works when I manually take the cookies from Chrome.
I can't see what's the problem!

Comment: I edited the question to include urls

Comment: What are you trying to get?

Comment: I'm trying to get a list of products in json format (which I can see in Chrome), but I'm getting html instead

Answer (score 0):

```
session = requests.Session()
session.get('http://www.auchandrive.fr/drive/pagestatique.pagetemplate.popuphandler.popinchangementmagasin.changermag/537?t:ac=PAGE_STATIQUE_ENGAGEMENTS')
response = session.post('http://www.auchandrive.fr/drive/rayon.productlist.pagination_0.topage/1?t:ac=3686973/3686997')
print(response.json)
```

Using the `json` attribute will fetch the JSON response. You can also use requests to make a persistent session, so the cookies are provided.

```
response.cookies #The cookies attribute
```